# My Bower files aren't being accessed through my browser

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bower

I went through cmd and installed Bootstrap, jQuery and Font-Awesome and all were saved in the bower_components file on my computer. The issue I think is that when I first saved these files, they wer in a different folder because all of my files for the webpage I am building were not consolidated. So I deleted my bower_components file and redownloaded everything into one folder with all of my other relevant files and folders saved underneath the one all-encompassing folder. However, when I open up my index.html file in Chrome, I get the error "`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`" even though when I go into Visual Studio Code and press Ctrl and click, it takes me directly to where the file is stored.

```
<link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The example code I looked at all has the exact same link text, so it must be an issue on my end with how I saved the files on my computer. I'm not sure how to fix this.

**Edit**: I went in and created dummy documents in each folder that was having trouble being found in Chrome and made sure that each link actually followed the path to that html file through Visual Studio Code. I then made an html document with links to each page. The only page that worked was the jQuery page, so I think that something is wrong with the font-awesome and bootstrap folders underneath my bower_components folder because the only links that don't seem to work are in these folders.

Comment: It's possible you may not be serving static assets. If you're using chrome, go to your inspector, click 'sources'. If you don't see your bower components to the sidebar on the left, then they aren't being served.

Comment: I would recommend trying it on a different browser like IE as a first attempt. Sometimes Chrome saves the source file and they don't get updated!

Comment: In general `bower_components` are used to create your custom build. You select what you need from these components and copy them (automatically) to your frontend directory. Visual Studio 2015 has "built in" task runners to do this. Feel free to check out [this solution](https://github.com/timver/Yambo/tree/master/YamboClient) and/or check the description for the IDE.

Comment: @ceckenrode yeah they don't show up in the developer's tools section, but my two jquery links at the bottom of the html work, which is strange. I'm thinking that something must be wrong with my bootstrap folder inside of the bower_components, but not the jquery folder.

Comment: @GHKarim It doesn't work on either Firefox or IE.

Comment: @JasmineMarieBouges it definitely sounds like a path issue or the bower_components not being served by the server to me. If you're using relative routes when serving static assets this may be an issue. ie doing bower_compoennts/bootstrap/dist/...etc instead of /bower_compoennts/bootstrap/dist/...etc (with the first forward slash)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that because I am using Windows, I cannot nest folders with long names inside of folders with long names because Windows will not follow a long path directory. Simple fix! Thanks everyone for your suggestions.